# validación de nombres en un arreglo enviado por teclado

Tags: c#

cómo puedo realizar un código en c# para que sólo pueda ingresar valores alfanuméricos que no sea mayor a 10 y que este nombre no se repita en un arreglo, almacenado por consola, es decir el nombre es lo que yo escriba desde el teclado
lo que tengo es esto:

```
public void RegistrarArticulo()
        {
            string desea = "SI";
            for (int i = 0; desea == "SI" || desea == null; i++)
            {
                do
                {
                    if (nombreArt.Count >= 1)
                    {

                        Console.WriteLine("no hay espacio ");
                        Console.ReadKey();
                        Console.WriteLine("Precione una tecla para volver al menú principal.");


                    }
                    desea = Console.ReadLine();
                    desea = desea.ToUpper();

                } while (desea == "SI");

                Console.WriteLine("INSERTAR DATO EN EL ARREGLO GENÉRICO");
                Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el nombre del articulo ");
                nom = Console.ReadLine();
                nombreArticulo.SetValue(nom, nombreArt.Count);
                string pattern =@"/^[a-z\d_]{4,5}$/i";


                Match result2= Regex.Match(nom,pattern);

                foreach (Match result in Regex.Matches(nom, pattern)) //bucle para obtener todas las coincidencias
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("IP encontrado: {0}", result.Value);
                }
                bool todoBien;//Se crea un valor booleano para validar el precio 
                do {

                    Console.Write("Ingrese el precio del articulo mayor a 0 y menor a 10000 ");

                    string valor = Console.ReadLine();
                    // Captura el dato entero que se desea insertar
                    precio = Convert.ToDouble(valor);
                    todoBien = (precio >= 0) && (precio <= 10000);//Se establece el rango que el usuario puede ingresar

                    precioJuguete.SetValue(precio, precioJug.Count);

                    if (!todoBien)
                        Console.WriteLine("Dato No es válido!");
                } while (!todoBien);
            // Se invoca el método Add de la clase genérica ArrayList
            nombreArt.Add(nom);
            precioJug.Add(precio); // Se agrega el Dato al Arreglo

            Console.WriteLine("\nDato agregado al arreglo !!!");

            Console.WriteLine("¿Deseas agregar otro articulo? Si/No.");
            desea = Console.ReadLine();
                desea = desea.ToUpper();

            }

            Console.ReadKey();

        }
```

Comment: Hola Edwin , para que me quede claro tu pregunta lo que intentas es ingresar alfanumericos de menos o igual longitud a 10 caracteres y que al agregarlo a un array no se repita ese valor. ¿Correcto?

Comment: Hola Víctor, correcto . Por ejemplo agrego la palabra "bola", cuando pregunto si deseo agregar otro nombre y si agrego la misma palabra me aparezca el mensaje "este nombre ya existe ", gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1):

Creamos las variables:

```
        List<string> array = new List<string>();
        string respuesta = "";
```

La logica:

```
            Console.WriteLine("Introduce una valor alfanumerico");
            respuesta = Console.ReadLine();
            // Leo lo que el usuario introduce si es mayor de 10 caracteres entro en un bucle que hasta que no lo introduzca correctamente no saldra, puedes remodelarlo a tu gusto.
            while (respuesta.Length > 10)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error , se ha exedido de los 10 caracteres de longitud");
                Console.WriteLine("Introduce una valor alfanumerico");
                respuesta = Console.ReadLine();
            }
            // Compruebo que la palabra no exista ya en el array, si existe muestro un mensaje al usuario y si no existe lo agrego
            if (array.Contains(respuesta))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error, este nombre ya existe");
            }
            else
                array.Add(respuesta);
```

Una opcion a tener encuenta es la siguiente:

```
HashSet<string> listaSinDuplicados = new HashSet<string>();
```

Puedes añadir automaticamente a la lista sin comprobar previamente que exista en ella, ya que el HashSet se encarga automaticamente de no almacenar duplicados

Comment: Excelente, funciona muy bien